Transfer data from GCP to Azure SQL
I am having a huge dataset and I am looking to transfer data from Big query table to Azure SQL.
I designed a java code to fetch data from Big query and persist it in SQL but I am facing out of memory exception.
Is there a way I could transfer data set from big query to Azure SQL efficiently?

can you add the error you are facing

why don't you use ADF to transfer data instead of java?

You can use ADF copy activity to transfer data from big query to Azure SQL database. Create Big Query linked service in ADF with related details as shown below:

Create Azure SQL database linked service with related credential for sink. Create source and sink datasets for copy activity with related data. For more information you can refer to the below documents:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery?tabs=data-factory

Azure Data Factory: Move data from Google Bigquery to Azure Blob


